# Using two different versions of Gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-sass

For a Rails4 application I want to use different version of bootstrap-sass gem (I have two different layouts, one is Bootstrap 2.3.2 and the other is Bootstrap 3).

The only way I can think is create custom groups at the gemfile, and requiring a specific gem at specific controller actions. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, this is not possible. you either need to have different gem-definitions or use a gem for one part and simply include bootstrap css and javascript in your application directly. you can even include both directly which i think is preferrable in this situation because i think it's less confusing. having said that, i think you should invest the time getting rid of one of the bootstrap versions instead.